# What is the best practice to keep JSON data up to date on a web page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm working on a Intranet application that manipulates data from a SQL server. The application has to support multiple users playing with the same data source / same tables. The application uses a [jQuery datatable library](http://datatables.net/) fed by a Ajax call to a JSON result action in my MVC Controller and some Ajax links rendered in the table allowing CRUD operations in a form of a modal popup window. When the popup submits the CRUD operation, it closes and calls a refresh on the datatable.

Everything is working wonderfully, however, I want that datatable to update if data is changed by another user (or another browser/tab) without having the refresh the table.

One method would be to poll a Hash from the server every X milliseconds and update if the hash changes, but I dont really like that option as I feel it could get out of hands pretty quickly with the amount of tables to manage.

I would like to know what you guys think of the polling method and if you have an alternative that would be more fluid, cleaner or simply a better practice for X reasons.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe [SignalR](http://signalr.net) can help you. Each time a command is send the application, you can push the results to each connected clients.

Comment: You should have posted this as an answer! ^^ Thanks! That's what I needed.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov posted its answer first. Let him get its (no more needed) points:)

Comment: Question was still on "No Accept Answer" cooldown ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know what you guys think of the polling method and if
>   you have an alternative that would be more fluid, cleaner or simply a
>   better practice for X reasons.

The alternative to polling is pushing which is far more efficient. Checkout [`SignalR`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/). And here's an [introductory blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx).

Comment: After reading over 100 posts by you, it was my time to get helped. :D Merci! This should do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using http://socket.io/ to create a websocket?

This will allows the server to push data to the relevant clients whenever your table updates and will also allow users to push their changes to your server without refreshing (just like ajax).

Socket.io also has a great fall back mechanism so it's supported on all major browsers (yes even IE6). http://socket.io/#browser-support

Comment: I dont have to support anything under IE 8, but I'll take a look at it. SignalR as suggested by Darin seems, however, a little more polished and easier to plug in. I'll still take a look at it however! Thanks!